# Is there any way to know all unused images of a website from image folder?

Tags: image

Is there any tool you know which can find all unused images of a website from image folder. I want to identfiy all those image in the image folder which are not being as a inline imge in HTML and CSS Background. Is it possible using any tools, techniques?

Comment: loop through each image file, and search its name in all your HTML and CSS files. And hope you don't have some JavaScript creating image names dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dreamweaver for this. In dreamweaver look in site files (press F8) in site menu select recreate site cache. Dreamweaver checks links in your Local Site folder and provides you with a report of all unused files, which you can either delete or re-link.

Hope this solves your problem.